# How can I run (execute) the xset (xorg) command in ubuntu 22.04 (wayland)?

Tags: linux, electron, embedded-linux, xorg, wayland

I am using the Ubuntu 22.04 Wayland windowing system. And I am working on an electron application where I need to execute the display turn off. Is there any way where I can execute the `xset -dpms force off`?

I have tried the [this](https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/linux-intel-graphics-video-tearing.html) solution but it is not working.

Comment: As the name suggests, `xset`, and the article you linked, only work for Xorg. In fact, you shouldn't experience any tearing at all on wayland out of the box!

Comment: Yes, in Wayland it's working fine. but can I execute `xset` command in Wayland? Is there any way for that?

Comment: No as `xset` is an xorg only command. That's like trying to run a bash command in cmd, they both might be shells but work completely differently. If you want wayland support, find an alternative to the tool that is tailored towards Wayland.

Comment: Understood! So is there any alternative way to turn OFF the display so that when I touch the screen it should appear ON (not the lock screen)? Based on my research, I haven't found any command that does the same `xset -dpms force off`.